# the trait cannot be made into an object in Vec

Tags: vector, rust, traits

I have the following code:

```rust
pub trait Handler<T: Clone>: Clone {
    fn invoke(&self) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct App<T: Clone> {
    handlers: Vec<Box<dyn Handler<T>>>,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    #[derive(Clone)]
    struct MyHandler<T: Clone> { tt: T }

    impl<T: Clone> Handler<T> for MyHandler<T> {
        fn invoke(&self) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> { () }
    }

    let app = App { handlers: vec![ MyHandler{ tt: 0 }, MyHandler{ tt: 5 } ] };
```

That generates a compile error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Handler` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     handlers: Vec<Box<dyn Handler<T>>>,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Handler` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

Even if I'm not trying to convert the trait into a concrete object.
I don't understand: the box struct should allow me to store an unknown sized type.

The aim is to store a `Vec` of `Handler` implementors in order to have `invoke` method for all object.

Comment: Hi there! I think your question is answered by ["How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353928/2408867). In short: if you have `Clone` as supertrait, your trait becomes non object-safe, meaning it cannot be made into an object. Please let us know if the linked answer sufficiently answers your question!

Comment: The error message is really not optimal, though. It should point to the `Clone` supertrait bound. But you probably want to read a bit about "object safety". For example [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44097369/2408867).

Comment: So, it's not possible to implement Clone trait for a struct with `Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` where MyTrait implements Clone?

Comment: It is possible, as the linked answer shows. It's just not possible to call `clone()` on a trait object (due to object safety). Therefore you have to build your own `clone` method that returns a boxed trait object.