# Rust - Generic of generic type into vec

Tags: generics, vector, rust

I need to create a Vec like this code :

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
trait TPlugin<'a, Config> where Config : Serialize + Deserialize<'a> {}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyConfig {}

struct MyPlugin1 {
  conf: MyConfig,
}
impl TPlugin<MyConfig> for MyPlugin1 {}
impl MyPlugin1 {
  pub fn new() -> MyConfig1 {
    MyConfig1{}
  }
}

fn main() {
  let my_vec: Vec<Box<dyn TPlugin<????>>> = Vec::new();
  my_vec.push(MyConfig1::new());
  my_vec.push(MyConfig2::new());
}
```

What is the code that I must add instead of "????"? I've tried `Box<dyn Serialize + Deserialize<'a>>` but rust tells me "the trait `serde::Serialize` cannot be made into an object".

I'm newbie on rust, so generics are obscure for me, like lifetimes. I'm from Java/Typescript.
In Java/Typescript I write:

```
let myVec: Vec<TPlugin<?>>;
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

First to focus on the core problem: To have a `Vec` of heterogenous objects, you must use dynamic dispatch, for example the `Box<dyn ...>`, which you already used successfully. But then inside you need another dynamic dispatch and this one is not possible. The `Box<dyn ...>` will end up being a "fat pointer" - one pointer pointing to the data, other pointer pointing to a virtual table for that type. [Virtual table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) is generated by the compiler and contains pointer to implementation of every method the type has. And here comes the problem, look at the `Serialize` trait:

```rust
pub trait Serialize {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where S: Serializer;
}
```

It has one method `serialize`, but this method is generic over `Serializer`. So really there is not one method, but *"infinite"* amount of methods, one for each possible `Serializer`. The compiler is not able to make virtual table for that, so `Serializer` can not be made into an (trait) object.

I would suggest you to define your own trait that describes what you want to do with `Config` and is [object safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096235/understanding-traits-and-object-safety). Perhaps methods for saving and loading with a specific `Serializer`, `toml` for example?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I suspected that a thing in this way. Tomorrow i will try it. I havn't done any language with memory manipulations since some years, i need to work on it! :)