# Using trait objects in structs without needing a type parameter

Tags: rust, traits

Is it possible to encapsulate a trait object inside a struct?

As far as I can tell, it requires `main` to know about the type `A`, no matter how many levels of modules are between. I'm trying to make a default implementation so the internals can remain that. My current use case is with the trait `yup_oauth2::GetToken`.

My current interface:

```
// root_project/main.rs
let auth_obj = build_auth_obj("user", "pass");
let root_caller: ApiUser<_> = ApiUser::new(auth_obj);

// api_user/lib.rs
pub struct ApiUser<A> {
    stored_api: API<A>,
}

impl ApiUser<A>
where
    A: yup_oauth2::GetToken,
{
    fn new(auth_obj: A) -> API<A> {
        stored_api: API::new(auth_obj)
    }
}

// api_def/lib.rs
struct Api<A> {
    auth: Refcell<A>,
}

impl<A> Api<A>
where
    A: yup_oauth2::GetToken,
{
    fn new(auth: A) -> Api<A> {
        API {
            auth: RefCell::new(auth),
        }
    }
}
```

My desired interface:

```
// root_project/main.rs
let root_caller: ApiUser = ApiUser::new("user", "pass");

// api_user/lib.rs
pub struct ApiUser {
    stored_api: API,
}

impl ApiUser {
    fn new(username: String, password: String) -> API {
        stored_api: API::new(username, password)
    }
}

// api_def/lib.rs
pub struct API(ApiImpl<dyn yup_oauth2::GetToken>);

struct ApiImpl<A> {
    auth: Refcell<A>,
}

impl<A> ApiImpl<A>
where
    A: yup_oauth2::GetToken,
{
    fn new(username: String, password: String) -> ApiImpl<A> {
        ApiImpl {
            auth: RefCell::new(build_auth_obj(username, password)),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I avoid a ripple effect from changing a concrete struct to generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912349/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it looks like what I want for writing my own modules. When I try it, I get "The trait 'yup_oauth2::GetToken' cannot be made into an object". Is there anything I can do in my code or would a PR for yup_oauth2 be the only way to enable it?

Comment: That's a limitation of the `GetToken` trait. See questions like [Understanding Traits and Object Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44096235/155423) for further details.

Comment: I see the issue is https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects. Just curious if there is any way I could work around it. I'm good to close the question if "not possible" is the answer in this particular case.

Comment: No, it's not currently possible. That being said, most people would just let the compiler infer the type and not try to be explicit: `let root_caller = ApiUser::new(auth_obj);`, just like you did with `auth_obj`.